# How do I show data in DataGridView of another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to show data in `DataGridView` which resides in `form1` and data reside in `form2`. `Form2` has a button named “ADD” which adds all the data in `form1`’s grid. Following code is working properly for the same form, how do I edit this code in order to show data from another form.

```
private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InputUserInfo frm1 = new InputUserInfo();

        frm1.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        frm1.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 120;
        frm1.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        int numberOfRows = frm1.dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        if (numberOfRows < 5)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            thumb_pic.Image.Save(ms, thumb_pic.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
            frm1.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(lbl_CP_UserID.Text, lbl_CP_Name.Text, img);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert Only 5 Images");
        }
        this.Hide();
        frm1.Show();

    }
```

Comment: Make public DatagridView in second form and you can access it when you create a second form instance like form2.datagridview

Comment: it works! .....but it always open new form1 so DataGridView has only one record again I enter new record it opens another form1 and show one record I want all 5 records in one grid one by one input from user.

Comment: you should be create form2 instance once, let me see the code...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have found a solution already but this might help someone in future.

The form (see pic [Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCFNP.jpg)) with grid

Code behind this Form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataGridView DataGridView1
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView1;
        }
    }

    private void btnAddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.TopMost = true;
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form (See pic [Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC9bN.jpg)) to add data into Form1 dataGridView

Code behind this Form:

```
    public Form1 frm1;

    public Form2(Form1 gridForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm1 = gridForm;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (frm1.DataGridView1.Rows.Count < 5)
        {
            frm1.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtOrderNo.Text, txtDesc.Text);
            frm1.DataGridView1.Refresh();
            txtOrderNo.Text = txtDesc.Text = "";
            if (frm1.DataGridView1.Rows.Count == 5) this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can only add up to 5 items.");
        }

    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```